# How to insert what I selected in combobox into an ACCESS database in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\db\\it.accdb");

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "insert into data (Requested By) values ('" + comboBox1.Items[0].ToString()+ "')";
cmd.Connection = con;

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted");
con.Close();
```

This is my code to insert what I selected in combobox into an ACCESS database in C#

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SelectedItem` It should be,

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into data ([Requested By]) values ('" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()+ "')";
```

Comment: thanks dear but I get this error    Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: copy the command text and run it on sql server and correct it there

Comment: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147217900
  Message=Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
  Source=Microsoft Office Access Database Engine
  ErrorCode=-2147217900
  StackTrace:

Comment: I will download it now

Comment: my password : 5827